# Google Sheets PHP API: 'valueInputOption' is required but not specified

Tags: google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api, google-api-php-client

I'm having trouble because my code suddenly doesn't work.

I get the error "'valueInputOption' is required but not specified", when using the batchUpdate() function of the Sheets API.

I worked fine until now, but suddenly I get the above mentioned error.

You can see the complete response here https://analyse.sengeguruen.dk/micro.php

This is my code

```
private function writeUrlData() {
      $totals = array(  'clicks' => 0,
                        'sales' => 0,
                        'revenue' => 0
                     );
      if(isset($this->microData[$this->landingpage]) && is_array($this->microData[$this->landingpage]) && count($this->microData[$this->landingpage]) > 0) {
         $cell_values = array();
         $service = new Google_Service_Sheets($this->sheets_client);
         
         /* Clear columns first*/
         $cellsToClear = 'Micro-niveau!A2:E99999';
         $clearRequestBody = new Google_Service_Sheets_ClearValuesRequest();
         $clearResult = $service->spreadsheets_values->clear($this->spreadsheetId, $cellsToClear, $clearRequestBody);

         $row_index = 2;
         foreach($this->microData[$this->landingpage] as $program_id => $url_data) {
            
            $clicks = isset($url_data['clicks']) ? $url_data['clicks'] : 0;
            $sales = isset($url_data['sales']) ? $url_data['sales'] : 0;
            $revenue = isset($url_data['revenue']) ? $url_data['revenue'] : 0;
            $epc = $clicks > 0 ? round($revenue / $clicks, 2) : 0;
            $program_name = $url_data['program_name'] != '' ? $url_data['program_name'] : $program_id;
            
            $totals['clicks'] += $clicks;
            $totals['sales'] += $sales;
            $totals['revenue'] += $revenue;

            $cell_values[] = new Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange(array('range' => 'Micro-niveau!A'.$row_index.':E'.$row_index, 'values' => [[
                    $program_name,
                    $clicks,
                    $sales,
                    $revenue,
                    $epc
                ]]));

            $row_index++;
         }
         
         // Insert row with totals
         $cell_values[] = new Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange(array('range' => 'Micro-niveau!A'.($row_index+1 ).':E'.($row_index+1), 'values' => [[
                 'Totals',
                 $totals['clicks'],
                 $totals['sales'],
                 $totals['revenue'],
                 round(($totals['revenue'] / $totals['clicks']), 2)
             ]]));
         
         $batchBody = new Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateValuesRequest([
               'valueInputOption' => 'USER_ENTERED',
               'data' => $cell_values
         ]);

         try {
            $batchResult = $service->spreadsheets_values->batchUpdate($this->spreadsheetId, $batchBody);
         } catch (Exception $e) {
            dump($e);
         }
         
         echo 'Done!';
      }
   }
```

I've tried finding solutions in older questions without any luck.

Comment: Hi, I cannot reproduce this behavior. I tested the API via `Try this` and also tested using a code similar to yours, with the `$batchBody` built the same way. In both cases the request successfully updated the sheet values. Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Are you sure you are using this exact code? Also, the link you provided requires entering some login data, so this info is not available. Consider providing the full error message in the question itself.

Comment: Ah sorry, have disabled the requirement of login data, to view the link :)

The entire error message is visible there.

Comment: I've tracked down where the problem is but not sure why it occurs.

The issues is the value which is right now $program_name in the loop.

If I replace that with a hardcoded text value, it works perfectly.

No matter which text I provide.

As viewable in the link now https://analyse.sengeguruen.dk/micro.php, you can see the actual values that is supposed to be saved to the sheet.

It's the first value in each row ie. "Nordicdream.dk", "Bedre Nætter - senge til hele familien", "Sengefabrikken.dk", "Sengetid".

So have tried hardcoding either of those values, and it worked fine.

Comment: It seems the issue is char encoding somehow.

If I change the line

`$program_name = $url_data['program_name'] != '' ? $url_data['program_name'] : $program_id;`

to

`$program_name = $url_data['program_name'] != '' ? mb_convert_encoding($url_data['program_name'], 'UTF-8') : $program_id;`

it works fine. It changes the Danish letter æ to ? so it's not a perfect solution, but tells us what the problem is.

When I detect the encoding of the original string with mb_detect_encoding() it returns ASCII

Comment: I tried writing the character `æ` to a sheet via API, and the request was successful, so I cannot reproduce this yet. Consider providing a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: I found out, that the problem was string encoding.

So adjusting this `$cell_values[] = new Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange(array('range' => 'Micro-niveau!A'.$row_index.':E'.$row_index, 'values' => [[
                    $program_name,
                    $clicks,` 

to

`$cell_values[] = new Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange(array('range' => 'Micro-niveau!A'.$row_index.':E'.$row_index, 'values' => [[
                    utf8_encode($program_name),
                    $clicks,`

made it work :)

Comment: Would you consider posting an answer explaining this?

Comment: Of course - done :)

Answer (score 0):

So I found out, that the issue was encoding of the text string for the variable $program_name.

So I changed the code to

```
private function writeUrlData() {
    $totals = array(  'clicks' => 0,
                       'sales' => 0,
                       'revenue' => 0
                   );
    if(isset($this->microData[$this->landingpage]) && is_array($this->microData[$this->landingpage]) && count($this->microData[$this->landingpage]) > 0) {
        $cell_values = array();
        $service = new Google_Service_Sheets($this->sheets_client);
         
        /* Clear columns first*/
        $cellsToClear = 'Micro-niveau!A2:E99999';
        $clearRequestBody = new Google_Service_Sheets_ClearValuesRequest();
        $clearResult = $service->spreadsheets_values->clear($this->spreadsheetId, $cellsToClear, $clearRequestBody);

        $row_index = 2;
        foreach($this->microData[$this->landingpage] as $program_id => $url_data) {
            
            $clicks = isset($url_data['clicks']) ? $url_data['clicks'] : 0;
            $sales = isset($url_data['sales']) ? $url_data['sales'] : 0;
            $revenue = isset($url_data['revenue']) ? $url_data['revenue'] : 0;
            $epc = $clicks > 0 ? round($revenue / $clicks, 2) : 0;
            $program_name = $url_data['program_name'] != '' ? $url_data['program_name'] : $program_id;
            
            $totals['clicks'] += $clicks;
            $totals['sales'] += $sales;
            $totals['revenue'] += $revenue;

            $cell_values[] = new Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange(array('range' => 'Micro-niveau!A'.$row_index.':E'.$row_index, 'values' => [[
                    utf8_encode($program_name),
                    $clicks,
                    $sales,
                    $revenue,
                    $epc
                ]]));

            $row_index++;
        }
         
        // Insert row with totals
        $cell_values[] = new Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange(array('range' => 'Micro-niveau!A'.($row_index+1 ).':E'.($row_index+1), 'values' => [[
                 'Totals',
                 $totals['clicks'],
                 $totals['sales'],
                 $totals['revenue'],
                 round(($totals['revenue'] / $totals['clicks']), 2)
             ]]));
         
        $batchBody = new Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateValuesRequest([
               'valueInputOption' => 'USER_ENTERED',
               'data' => $cell_values
        ]);

        try {
            $batchResult = $service->spreadsheets_values->batchUpdate($this->spreadsheetId, $batchBody);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            dump($e);
        }
         
        echo 'Done!';
    }
}
```